# Unable to mount linux share on another linux machine

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba4

When I tried to mount Ubuntu file share on another ubuntu machine, getting below error:

> mount error(13): Permission denied
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Currently Linux file server is joined to AD.
When did `net ads testjoin`, received `Join is OK`

even tried with `sec=ntlmv2`, no luck and receiving below error:

> mount error(22): Invalid argument
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

I am using command:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=test,domain=som.win.testing.edu //10.138.0.2/demoADShare /mnt
```

Any help please?

Comment: Typically I would expect you to need a password as well

Comment: Even I tried with password after username, but still I am getting same error. Please let me know if you need smb.conf file to review. I am suspecting that I might be using some wrong configuration........ but unable to figure out. Thank you

Comment: Finally I made modifications to my smb.conf and able to mount shares. But all shares are opening for all users, whereas i dint give anonymous any where. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @HBruijn atlast I could able to resolve issue by commenting            
`idmap backend = tdb2` and uncommenting `idmap config *` Thank you for your support